# What can run VB.NET programs? Very amature programmer

Tags: android, vb.net, windows-phone

Going to preface by saying I know very little about programming, I use VB.NET to make simple number crunching programs. I want to know if there is any way I can use a VB.NET program on my android smart phone  and/or an android tablet. Also could the windows phone run them? Thank you.

Comment: MS Operating systems only. This includes MS Phone an windows PC's.

Comment: If you want to run .NET apps on Android, take a look at Xamarin.  Or just be patient, Microsoft *just today* announced that the entire .NET stack is being open sourced and they're targeting official releases for Mac/Linux.